# Custom mesh jittering in Mujoco environment in OpenAI gym

Tags: reinforcement-learning, openai-gym

I've tried modifying the `FetchPickAndPlace-v1` OpenAI environment to replace the cube with a pair of scissors. Everything works perfectly except for the fact that my custom mesh seems to jitter a few millimeters in and out of the table every few time steps. I've included a picture mid-jitter below:

[image]

As you can see, the scissors are caught mid-way through the surface of the table. How can I prevent this? All I've done is switch out the code for the cube in `pick_and_place.xml` with the asset related to the scissor mesh. Here's the code of interest:

```
<body name="object0" pos="0.0 0.0 0.0">
            <joint name="object0:joint" type="free" damping="0.01"></joint>
            <geom size="0.025 0.025 0.025" mesh="tool0:scissors" condim="3" name="object0" material="tool_mat" class="tool0:matte" mass="2"></geom>
            <site name="object0" pos="0 0 0" size="0.02 0.02 0.02" rgba="1 0 0 1" type="sphere"></site>
</body>
```

I've tried playing around with the coordinates of the position and geometry but to no avail. Any tips? Replacing `mesh="tool0:scissors"` with `type="box"` gets rid of the problem entirely but I'm back to square one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As suggested by [Emo Todorov in the MuJoCo forums](http://www.mujoco.org/forum/index.php?threads/custom-mesh-jittering-in-mujoco-environment-in-openai-gym.3860/):

1. Replace the ground box with a plane and
   use MuJoCo 2.0. The latest version of the collision detector
   generates multiple contacts between a mesh and a plane, which
   results in more stable simulation. But this only works for
   plane-mesh, not for box-mesh.
2. The better solution is to break the mesh into several meshes, and include them as multiple geoms in the same body. Then MuJoCo will construct the convex hull of each sub-mesh, resulting in multiple contact points (even without the special plane mechanism mentioned above) and furthermore it will be a better approximation to the actual object geometry.